# How to reproduce this layout?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, layout

I'd like to reproduce this layout (especially the sections + the bottom and the top parts of the paper).

[image]

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, french, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\title{\textsc{\fbox{Rappel de trigonométrie}}}
\date{}
\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section})}
    \section{\color{red}Valeurs remarquables et formules élémentaires}

Voici un tableau des valeurs remarquables concernant les fonctions trigonométriques: 

\begin{center}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l *{6}{>{\displaystyle}c} @{}}
\toprule
x       & 0 &\frac{\pi}{6}   &\frac{\pi}{4}   &\frac{\pi}{3}   &\frac{\pi}{2}&\pi\\ 
\midrule
\cos(x) & 1 &\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{1}{2}     &0            &-1 \\ 
\addlinespace
\sin(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{2}     &\frac{\sqrt2}{2}&\frac{\sqrt3}{2}&1            &0  \\ 
\addlinespace
\tan(x) & 0 &\frac{1}{\sqrt3}&1               &\sqrt3          & /      &0  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{center}
\par
Les fonctions $\cos$ et $\sin$ sont reliées par la formule suivante:
\begin{center}
\fbox{$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean the `running head` and `running foot`? If yes, please check the `fancyhdr` package, which having good `documentation` too...

Comment: Well the red and green stuff as well as the top and bottom part of this sheet of papaer (with AM 2 etc)

Comment: Are you obliged to reproduce this layout _exactly_? Sorry but I find the underlines horrible :) (and the huge use of colors, too)

Comment: Well i'm just looking for some kind of model for my math lessons and I have yet to find a good one haha

Comment: For  headers a footers use  `fancyhdr` as commented ,  for the rest I am agree with CarLaTeX. Maybe other colors  (like  `red!30!black` with `xcolor` package instead of red)  occasionally (only chapters or main sections... ),  but underlines and boxes ... My suggestion is stay with the default format  as long as possible. If definitively cannot live without change something, think twice. The default classes has been designed by experts and are hardly improved but easily degraded by a custom design.

Comment: Ok well thank you all ^sry I'm new to this